# Aplicação em Asp Net não executa

Tags: c#, .net, asp

Alguém conseguiria me explicar o motivo pelo qual, ao executar minha aplicação em Asp Net ela não executa, apresentando a mensagem "Erro de Servidor no Aplicativo '/'."?

Tela de erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo RouteConfig.cs:

```
 namespace Praca_Projeto
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Meu controlador chama PracasController.

Alguém poderia, por favor, me dizer onde está o problema? Eu já alterei o nome do controller em RouteConfig mas não deu certo.

Comment: Você está executando a aplicação enquanto está com o index.cshtml aberto? Remove da barra de endereços "/Views/Pracas/Index.cshtml"

Comment: George, eu estou tentando executar com F5. Removi as informações da barra e não funcionou. Atualizei a imagem.

Comment: Se seu controller chama `PracasController` dentro do `MapRoute` deveria indicar isso e não `Home`

Comment: Troquei como você falou e continua o mesmo erro. O MapRoute está assim: routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "PracasController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

Comment: Consegui resolver, meu controller estava como "PracasController", então troquei para "Pracas" e deu certo.

Comment: Obrigado George Wurthmann e Barbetta pela ajuda!

Comment: Pode ser erro no IIS Express, clique com botão direito e Sair no IIS, próximo ao relógio do Windows.
Outra coisa é rodar no MS Edge ao invés do Chrome que trás muitos problemas de depuração.